# Want to lookup to adjacent cell if the cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table

```
Table1
ID Name
1. foo, baz
2. baz, ,bar
3. xyz, ,
```

```
Table2
Name Class
foo First
baz Third
bar Third
abc Second
```

I have split the Name column into three different columns. And, now I want to lookup cells from these three columns at same time and combine the results.

For example: for Name `foo,baz` the output will be `First Third`. And, for `xyz, ,`, the output will be just a blank cell.

I am doing it like below
`=IF(DP15<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DP15,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,FALSE),""),IF(DQ15<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DQ15,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,FALSE),""),IF(DR15<>"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(DR15,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,FALSE),""),"")))`

It is not giving me the desired result. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A1:C1,F:F,0)),""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

If one does not have TEXTJOIN concatenate three lookups:

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A1,F:F,0)),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(B1,F:F,0)),"")&" "&IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(C1,F:F,0)),""))
```

[image]